# How the replacement of auth_token field is working in below scenario

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def facebook
        @facebook ||=  Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
    end
end
```

In the rails console

```
user = User.first 
user.facebook.get_object("me")
```

First question is, User model has a column called oauth_token, which is magically getting replaced in `Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)` here, even though I am not passing oauth_token explicitly

Second question, what is the need of caching @facebook variable here? I am following this rails casts tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqeZy2G2C1g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@First question

What do you mean by getting replaced? 
From what I see when initializing API (`API.new(oauth_token)`) you are passing `ouath_token` that is assigned to specific user. When calling `User.first` you're loading first user from database, and ActiveRecord automatically assigns oauth_token to newly created instance. If ouath_token was never saved (thus present in db record) it would be `nil`.

@Second question

This is in general done for performance reasons in order to avoid multiple API calls within same request. However, usually response from API call is cached not the API instance itself. Maybe that Koala API instance calls webservice directly in constructor (in its `initialize` method).

My note - keeping such methods like `facebook` calling external webservice within `User` model ends with **very difficult** to change code. 
It's better to move it somewhere out from this model.